# How to move file from directory A to directory B in remote server?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using JSch to connect to SFTP in a website which is made from GWT.
I had read a little example of `sftpChannel.get()`, `sftpChannel.rename()`, `sftpChannel.rm()`

But I didn't find a solution that copy a file from remote server `a` directory to remote server `b` directory.

For example, I want to copy file from `/appl/user/home/test/temp` to `/appl/user/home/test/`. Filename = `abc.jpg`.

I stunned here for few hours since most of the solution from network is getting file from remote server to local, or uploading file from local to remote server.

```
String existingfile = "abc.jpg";
String newfile = "123.jpg";
FileDirectory = "/appl/user/home/test/";
sftp.cd(FileDirectory+"temp/");
sftp.rename(newfile, FileDirectory+newfile);
```

Let's say, `abc.jpg` is existing in `/appl/user/home/test/`

And I upload a `123.jpg` in `/appl/user/home/test/temp/`.

Now, I want to move `123.jpg` to `/appl/user/home/test/` and remove `abc.jpg` in `/appl/user/home/test/`.

What should I do?

Comment: I came here looking for the "move" command, it's very simple - use .rename()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like `SftpChannel.rename();` need to use full path of file instead of cd to the directory that the file I am going to move.

```
String existingfile = "abc.jpg";
String newfile = "123.jpg";
FileDirectory = "/appl/user/home/test/";
sftp.cd(FileDirectory+"temp/");
if (sftp.get( newfile ) != null){
    sftp.rename(FileDirectory + "temp/" + newfile , 
        FileDirectory + newfile );
    sftp.cd(FileDirectory);
    sftp.rm(existingfile );
}
```

Comment: I have a query, is/ is not sftp.get(newFile) inside the if condition on fifth line going to download the new file into the system on which  this program is running?

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
            ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) this.session.openChannel("sftp");
            channelSftp.connect();              
            logger.info("Home directory: {}",channelSftp.getHome());
            logger.info("Go to directory: {}",pathSFTP);
            logger.info("Move files to directory: {} ",destinationPath);
            
            channelSftp.cd(pathSFTP);
            
            List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> filesFound = channelSftp.ls(fileExtension);
            
            logger.info("Files [{}] found ",filesFound.size());
            
            //Move to path processed
            for (LsEntry lsEntry : filesFound) {
                String pathDes = destinationPath+"/"+lsEntry.getFilename();
                channelSftp.rename(lsEntry.getFilename(), pathDes);
                logger.info("Moved to {} ",pathDes);
            }
            
            //Close Connection
            channelSftp.exit();
            channelSftp.disconnect();
            
            logger.info("All files has been downloaded successfully");
            
        } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
            logger.error("Error move files directory [{}]",destinationPath);
            logger.error("An error has occurred while Move files {}", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Note that answers that contain only code are generally considered to be poor quality. Can you [edit] your answer and add an explanation of how the code works? I encourage you to take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Answer (score -1):

You can write a normal Java `FileInputStream`and `FileOutputStream`code and instead of using paths like these `/appl/user/home/test/temp` use full path with its IpAddress or remote server name + your path eg `myremoteserver/appl/user/home/test/temp`

Comment: But i don't want to make the File transfer to client side. My SFTP server located at Unix, so it is the absolute path. Isn't FileInputStream and FileOutputStream is making the file from SFTP to local (client side) ?
I think i should not making the file from SFTP (Server side) to client side then to SFTP again.